# How does the code work?

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I am trying to check how the loop works hence, I am displaying the value of n in the for-loop but it doesn't seem to work. Why doesn't **n** get displayed and how is the code (loop) working?

```
h=0.3;
x=0:h:0.8;
for n=4:length((x)-1)
  disp(n)
  % Doing something here
  end
```

Comment: Looks like misplaced parentheses for your length expression ?

Comment: Yes, thanks, I realised that a moment ago. It should be (length(x)-1).

Comment: Please use workspace window or output from the name to examine the value of variables. For your question, the code 4:length((x)-1), 4:2 in fact, returns a empty vector. Thus n is empty and nothing can be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

`0:0.3:0.8`  is `[0.00000    0.30000    0.60000]`, so the for loop never executes, as `length((x)-1)` is 3.